# Add multiple checkboxes based on input length in Angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

Currently, I have a single checkbox in my Angular application which I plot using the HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" value="Apple">
<label for="box1"> Apple</label>
```

However, I now need to tweak the functionality such that the number of checkboxes is dependant on the array input. Also, the contents of the arrays should be the labels for the checkboxes.

For ex:

If my array is `arr = ['Apple', 'Mango','Banana']`, I should get 3 checkboxes (as the length of arr is 3) like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `*ngFor` for acheiving this

**`app.component.html`**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{item}}" [value]="item " (change)="getItem($event)">
    <label for="{{item}}"> {{item }}</label>
</div>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
arr = ['Apple', 'Mango','Banana'];

getItem(item) {
   //check if the checkbox selected or not
   if(item.target.checked) {
      let value = item.target.value;
      console.log(value);
      //Do your thing here 
   }
}
```

**Hope this help's :)**

Comment: you will have some issue if all input get the same id.
If array value are unique you can pass `item` instead of `"box1` or use index

Comment: @MskSatheesh I have used this and it works. Is there any way that when I click any of the checkbox, its corresponding label will be received by the backend?

Comment: Updated the answer.check now pls @AkhilKintali

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to achieve this.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.status" (click)="checked(i)">
    <label> {{item.name}}</label>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of arr;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{item}}" [value]="item ">
    <label for="{{item}}"> {{item }}</label>
</div>
```

Class

```
array = [
    { name: "Apple", status: true },
    { name: "Mango", status: true },
    { name: "Banana", status: true }
  ];
  checked(i) {
    this.array[i].status = !this.array[i].status;
  }
  arr = ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana"];
```

You can also find working link: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ozcygp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)